# How to do a loop until last row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to perform a loop on my spreadsheet that works its way down the rows until it hits the last row in the datasheet.

I have a formula in cell `P1` and I copy it into `G1` and the loop works its way down infinitely to `G200`, `G201`, etc. How do I make it stop at the last row?

This is the code I have already tried.

```
Dim output As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set output = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
output.Range("P1").Value = "=SUM(Q1,R1)"

Do Until Lastrow = True
    output.Range("P1").Copy Destination:=output.Cells(i, 7)
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

I currently have 21 rows of data (this is not static though) and it should loop essentially 21 times in this instance.

Comment: Your `Lastrow` variable doesn't get updated in your loop so it will loop forever

Comment: Use a For loop: `For i = 1 to LastRow` - but you don't need to loop.

Answer (score 4):

No loop needed:

```
Sub NU112()
    Dim output As Worksheet
    Set output = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = output.Range("A" & output.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    output.Range("G1:G" & Lastrow).Formula = "=SUM(Q1,R1)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For loops work better for looping through cells. I put everything in a with block so you don't need to constantly qualify ranges.

```
Dim output As Worksheet
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim i As Integer

Set output = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
with output
    Lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    output.Range("P1").formula = "=SUM(Q1,R1)"
    for i = 1 to lastrow
        .Cells(i, 7).value = .cells(1, 16).value
    next i
end with
```

Comment: Actually... it's the `For Each` loop which works better with cells :P just a pointer.

Comment: If you load it into an array then yeah, there would be no difference between ```for``` and ```for each``` using range except you can step a ```for```. (as far as I know, though I've never tested it.)

Comment: `For Each`is the best loop when working directly into the worksheet (cells, ranges, worksheets, workbooks..) and `For i` is the best loop when working with arrays.

Comment: Is there actually a noticeable difference? I've never had it slow down looping through 100k+ rows.

Comment: It should be, that's what I've read here from peers with a lot of reputation...